# Retrieve NFT data and transfer to another account using phantom wallet

Tags: javascript, solana, nft

I'm developing a NFT donation application for a non profit organization. Once user login to the web application users can connect their phanthom wallet.Once it connect have to retrieve connected wallet NFT data to application dashboard. And users should have to donate their NFT using a donate button.I'm using react js and I wanted to know how to do this

I wanted to know how to retrieve NFT data from Phantom wallet and showing on the dashboard and then implement donate button to donate user's NFT via the web application using connected phantom wallet.

Comment: what have you already tried / where did you get stuck?

Comment: The phantom wallet is connected to the web application. I followed this one https://www.cryptorustacean.com/posts/connecting-phantom-wallet

Comment: And at which point of this are you stuck exactly? What errors do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to retrieve connected wallet NFT to frontend and donate selected NFT via a donate button.